Separably unirational variety is separably rationally connected
A variety over a field $k$ is called separably rationally connected if there is a variety Y along with a morphism $u:U=Y \times \mathbb{P}^1 \to X$ such that the map $u \times u : U \times_{Y} U \to X \times X$ is dominant and smooth at generic point. 
A variety X over a field $k$ is called separably unirational if there is a dominant map $\mathbb{P}^n \to X$ such that the associated map between function field is a separable extension.
Then separably unirational varieties are separably rationally connected. I think the Y would be some component of $Hom(\mathbb{P}^1, X)$ but I cannot show that u is smooth at generic point. Kindly provide an explicit argument.

Not sure this works, but you could try writing $\mathbb{P}^n$ as the symmetric product $Q_n=Sym^n(\mathbb{P}^1)$. Now compose with the quotient map $(\mathbb{P}^1)^n \times \mathbb{P}^1 \to Q_n$ which is generically etale
